# OnClick() method doesn't work in TextView

Tags: java, android, android-layout, navigation, textview

I have a `textView` with `OnClick` method to navigate another activity. But, If i pressed that text it doesn't navigate. But If i used `Button` instead `TextView`, it works perfectly. Can't use `OnClick` method in `TextView`?

My XML Code;

```
<TextView
    android:onClick="webClick"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
    android:text="Chapter 1"
    android:textSize="25dp" />
```

My Java Code:

```
public void webClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Webview.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: add this attribute `android:clickable="true"`

Comment: well. its works. thanks. add this as answer. i will mark this.

Comment: posted the comment as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this attribute to textview

```
       android:clickable="true"
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:clickable

`android:clickable`

**Defines whether this view reacts to click events.**

**Must be a boolean value, either "true" or "false".**

This may also be a reference to a resource (in the form "@[package:]type:name") or theme attribute (in the form "?[package:][type:]name") containing a value of this type.

This corresponds to the global attribute resource symbol clickable.

Related Methods
setClickable(boolean)

Comment: @MohamedThaufeeq i understand that it is the forum rules. thanks.

Comment: @Raghunandan can u help me on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18054704/how-to-use-scroll-view-in-android?noredirect=1#comment26421587_18054704

Answer (score 0):

try by adding  `android:clickable="true"`

```
<TextView
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="webClick"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
    android:text="Chapter 1"
    android:textSize="25dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your code with this

```
<TextView
    android:id = "+@id/tvName"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="webClick"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
    android:text="Chapter 1"
    android:textSize="25dp" />
```