# How to use Scroll View In Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview, android-scroll

I have use two scroll views for two different layout. And those two layouts are inside a Linear Layout.

Here is my XML file. I don't why `ScrollView` is not working for me

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/flightResultData"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/onewayflightLogo"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/spicejet" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/onewayflightName"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="SpiceJet" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/onewayflightNumber"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="9W - 496" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/onewayflightTime"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:minLines="1"
                            android:text="06:00 - 7:05"
                            android:textSize="12dp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/onewayflightDuration"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:minLines="1"
                            android:text="1h 35m | Non Stop"
                            android:textSize="10dp" />
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/onewayflightAmount"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:minLines="1"
                            android:text="Rs 200000"
                            android:textSize="12dp" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
                <View
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />
               <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/retrunflightLogo"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/spicejet" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/retrunflightName"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="SpiceJet" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/retrunflightNumber"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="9W - 496" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/retrunflightTime"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:minLines="1"
                            android:text="06:00 - 7:05"
                            android:textSize="12dp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/retrunflightDuration"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:minLines="1"
                            android:text="1h 35m |Non Stop"
                            android:textSize="10dp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/retrunflightAmount"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:minLines="1"
                            android:text="Rs 200000"
                            android:textSize="12dp" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is my main layout in which I am inflating my above xml dynamically through a loop

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/flightResultData"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/sortFlightLayouts"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>
```

And in my activity code I am doing this:

```
void setTestResultData(){

    flightResult=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.flightResultData);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams flightDetailsLayout = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams forUnderLine = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    forUnderLine.setMargins(0,0, 0, 0);
    for(int i=0;i < 13;i++){
        LinearLayout flightInformations=(LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.flight_details_layout, null);
        flightResult.addView(flightInformations);
    }
}
```

Comment: is it not possible to use listviews instead?

Comment: @AndroSelva no i have to use linear layouts see the image link that i have posted u will easily understand what i have to do

Comment: @Gaurav use a listview add the linear layouts as header and footer. i have suggested the same before and i am suggesting it now also. Actually use a gridview. add the header and footer to the gridview. Recommend using a gridview.

Comment: @Raghunandan pls see the image link that i have added .how could i do this with listview.and the flight details is in different layout as u see the code i am inflating it at run time

Comment: i just want a scroll view on both side that scroll independently each layout

Comment: @Gaurav why can't you use a listview/gridview? you can inflatea custom layout for each row in the listview. listview/gridview handles the scroll. I don't understand why you can use listview/griview?. I have checked the image before posting my suggestion.

Comment: i just want a help from u to put scroll on both side

Comment: @Gaurav i am not aware of that. sorry i can't help you further. but i am at loss as to why you can't use a listview or gridview.? what is your reason?

Comment: so help me how could i do this in listview /gridview .i am new android so if u help me i will be thankfull to u

Comment: @Gaurav study custom listview http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-arrayadapter/ .   check this       http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15261088/gridview-with-two-columns-and-auto-resized-images

Comment: @Gaurav you are welcome the first link does not open. you can google search the same as custom listview. use a gediview with a image and text and the linear layouts and header and footer that should help.

Comment: i have already seen that ....i have used that but these are not working for me still thank u very much

Comment: @Gaurav why is that not working for you. post your code. Still want yo use scrollview go ahead with it.

Comment: @Raghunandan as u r suggestion i am trying to use ListView for my page can u help me with sample code how could i do this.i have seen also the example but i am not able to implement them  for my layout ..please help me i need a start how to use that

Comment: @Gaurav form the picture you have a back button while android has hardware back button that does the job. Secondly use a gridview with textview's and imageview. with two culumns. Add the other linearlayout as a header and a footer. for the sample i don't have time to code for your layout. If i have time i will post the solution

Comment: @Raghunandan i have done that through a Scroll View but i am facing one issues can help me out on that

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a simple, two-column organization:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <!-- stuff goes here that should appear above the scrolling areas -->

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/left_side_scroller"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <!-- contents of left side go here -->
    </ScrollView>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/right_side_scroller"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <!-- contents of right side go here -->
    </ScrollView>

    <!-- stuff goes here that should appear below  the scrolling areas -->
</LinearLayout>
```

Alternatively (and perhaps better) it looks like you should be using two `ListView` elements instead of two `ScrollView` elements. Each `ListView` would have the same layout parameters as shown above for the `ScrollView`. Since a `ListView` manages scrolling internally, you then don't need `ScrollView` at all.

Also, you probably want the entire layout to fill the screen, with the "filter" and "sort" elements always at the bottom. To achieve this effect,the top-level layout should have `android:layout_height="fill_parent"` instead of `"wrap_content"`. Also, the scrollable areas should have `android:layout_height="0dp"` and a non-zero weight (which they already do).

Comment: i am new in android can u help me for some sample code how could i use listview for my design that have two layouts on left and right side

Comment: @Gaurav - Take a look at the [guide topic on `List View`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html) to learn how a `ListView` works. It will teach you how to make a layout with a single `ListView`. (You don't want a `ListActivity`, however, because it only deals with a single `ListView`. So don't follow that part of the guide.) Then just substitute two `ListView`s in place of the `ScrollView`s I have in my answer. You'll end up with a layout that has two independently scrolling lists of rows like you want. It's a bit complicated, but so are your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

if you are display your scrollview in Horizontal Linear Layout and given a weight to scrollview then set width of Scrollview to "0dp"

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
```

and if it is vertical then

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
```

also set your main LinearLayout height to fill parent

Comment: So simple take a horizontal scrollview

Comment: i need verticall scroll view ob both the layout

Comment: Just paste your screen or scratch...so it will be easier for me to understand and flow also

Comment: updated my question please see the code i have a border between the towo details i want them in to the scroll view