# Create a layout with two layout for right and left side .having a Listview to scroll it

Tags: android

I have created this layout and want to be divided in two parts same of left and right side of the page. That have a scroll in that for scroll I want to use `ListView` Please help me on this    I want left side independent scorll and the right side independent scroll

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="5dip" >

            <!--  ListRow Left sied Thumbnail image -->
            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/thumbnail" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="3dip"      
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dip">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/if"
                    android:layout_width="50dip"
                    android:layout_height="42dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/fc"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/test"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/ty"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thumbnail"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="#040404"
                android:typeface="sans" 
                android:textSize="15dip"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/dd"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/flightTime"
                android:textColor="#343434"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
                android:text="" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/cc"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/flightDuration"
                android:textColor="#343434"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
                android:text="" />

        </RelativeLayout>
```

This is my listView

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="#b5b5b5"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is how i am trying to create the layout with the listview

http://s17.postimg.org/x1fcutey7/sample.png

Comment: use a grdiview with two columns

Comment: you want a listview inside a scrollview? "That have a scroll in that for scroll I want to use ListView". elaborate pls.

Comment: basically i want listview with 2 rows and multiple column

Comment: can you post a snap shot of how it should look?

Comment: @Raghunandan i have updated the image link please see that

Comment: @Pankaj do you want two ListViews side by side?

Comment: @MocialovBoris yes and the Layout i have created is single row

Comment: listview will provide me scroll on both sides layout sepratetly

Comment: so what is the problem? you have created one ListView, you have to create one more ListView in order to accomplish what you are looking for

Comment: @MocialovBoris yes op must have two listviews but still its the same content image and textviews better to use gridview and each column won't scroll individually

Answer (score 0):

Use the `android:numColumns="2"` in your `GridView` widget

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/grid"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
    android:verticalScrollbarPosition="right"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">
</GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a gridview with two columns. You will need to ad dividers and customize according to your needs.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


/** Called when the activity is first created. */

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test);
    GridView gv = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid);
    CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this);
    gv.setAdapter(adapter);

}
class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    LayoutInflater mInflater;
    public CustomAdapter(Context mainActivity) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mainActivity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 20;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub ViewHolder holder; 
         ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) { 
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, 
                    parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.iv = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1); 
            holder.tv1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1); 
            holder.tv2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2); 
            holder.tv3 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView3); 
            holder.tv4 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView4); 
           convertView.setTag(holder); 
       } else { 
           holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag(); 
       } 

      // set data here

       return convertView; 

    }

}
static class ViewHolder
{
    ImageView iv;
    TextView tv1,tv2,tv3,tv4;
}
}
```

test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/grid"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
    android:verticalScrollbarPosition="right"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">
</GridView>
```

row.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="43dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

snap shot

[image]

Edit:

If you want the left side and right side to scroll individually you will need two listviews. One for the left and one for the right. Have custom adapters for both the listviews.

Comment: this is exactly what i wanted but i want the seprate scrolling on the left and right side

Comment: that is not possible with the above design. have you seen the google play market.

Comment: scroll is coming on the complete page i want to be separate for the left and right side layout

Comment: @Pankaj with the above design its not possible. ignore this answer if it does not help. pls mention the same in your question about the left side independent scorll and the right side independent scroll.

Comment: @Pankaj i am not sure but i guess this question was asked by another user gaurav. The snap shots looks similar to the flight one gaurav posted. seems strange to me.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18054704/how-to-use-scroll-view-in-android. the snap shot was removed. question edited.